# How to setup ArrayList for serialization and avoid Type was not expected

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to pass array list to SOAP service:

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList
{
    "simple",
    "4",
    "two",
    new StringKeyValuePair {Key = "name", Value = "product name"}
};

[Serializable]
public struct StringKeyValuePair
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Call looks like:

```
 client.call(sessionId, "product.create", arrayList);
```

And WSDL looks like:

```
<message name="call">
   <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
   <part name="resourcePath" type="xsd:string"/>
   <part name="args" type="xsd:anyType"/>
</message>
```

Problem is, that soap client can't serialize it, as StringKeyValuePair is not expected type. I can not wrap it into class as a property, as that would result in additional xml, that soap service will not understand (can not change soap service).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a problem and a solution. Thing is, that client was unaware what types to expect, as long as args parameter type was any. 
So solution was to add KnowType to operation (in sample below it is added to all operations):

```
   foreach (var operation in client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
   {       
       operation.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(StringKeyValuePair));
   }
```

Then it works as supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it in serialized.

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList
{
    "simple",
    "4",
    "two",
    "<KeyValuePair><Pair Key=\"name\">product name</Pair></KeyValuePair>"
};
```

Is there no way to pass in a type safe object like a List or an Array?

Comment: well, I had this idea from very beginning, but considering it a hack, I'll use it only if there won't be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `XmlInclude` attribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx

```
public class MyService: WebService {

   [WebMethod()]
   [XmlInclude(typeof(StringKeyValuePair))]
   public ArrayList YourMethod() {
      //...
   }
}
```

Comment: this does not work, exception message is offering this attribute. Also not working SoapInclude attribute.

Comment: Maybe you're using some other class inside `StringKeyValuePair` implementation? Could you post service method signature and code you use to call it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that exception is mentioning `StringKeyValuePair` explicitly. Apart from XML/SoapInlcude I have no ideas. Please post the code, maybe it'll help.

Comment: I've updated question with StringKeyValuePair implementation.

Comment: Have you used 'Update web reference' after adding Xml/SoapInclude?

Comment: May be I wasn't clear - I can not affect webservice, also webservice is written using php, and these attributes to my understanding belong to webservice, not to client.